# How do i solve this error of speech recognition unknown error?

Tags: speech-recognition

Can Anybody Help Me Out Please! , Why am I getting this error and how to solve it

The Error(  if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError )

Thanks

Comment: Does [this post](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/383#issuecomment-432787947) help you ?